# "Error: Inject() must be called from an injection context" after importing angularx-social-login

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and I've been trying to integrate social media login into my project following this tutorial:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login
I have installed the angularx-social-login library and following dependencies 
-tslint

-@angular/code

-@angular/common

-rxjs

and now I have "Error: Inject() must be called from an injection context".

I have tried preserveSymlinks in angular.json file, but it didn't work.

Screenshot:

```
Error: Inject() must be called from an injection context console screen
```

[image: 1]

My app.module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DaneComponent } from './dane/dane.component';
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";


let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("I'm aware that I need to put app ID here")
  },
  {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("I'm aware that I need to put app ID here")
  }
]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DaneComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And .ts file containing methods:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "angularx-social-login";
import { FacebookLoginProvider, GoogleLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";
import { SocialUser } from "angularx-social-login";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dane',
  templateUrl: './dane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dane.component.css']
})
export class DaneComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: SocialUser;
  private loggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = (user != null);
    });
  }

  signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  signInWithFB(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  } 

  signOut(): void {
    this.authService.signOut();
  }

}
```

Comment: You should post an issue in the github repo about this. This is too much specific to the library you are trying to use... https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

I have installed angularx-social-module in the wrong directory instead of in my project.